# What is better for me: get a personal trainer, or, a program from a personal trainer?

Tags: health, personal-training, physical-therapy, functional-strength

I have had this personal trainer for a couples of times, and she seems really smart in her field of work. I feel I could actual see results from her work. Is it better for me to get a program to work on my own, or, to get her to be my personal trainer for a couple of weeks? I have a shoulder injury and I really can't stand it any more and would like to over come the issue. Would I be getting more result from her, or, more result from her program? I mean she is going to be making sure that all the exercise is done in the right form and that functional training exercises are effective. If I did it by myself, it may not be done correctly.

Another question: has any body had any issues, like in the shoulder and or another part that they got a personal trainer and saw result from their work?

I know that personal trainers cost money and program is the cheaper option. But at this point I don't mind seeing a personal trainer one or two month, if I am going to see genuine results!

Answer (score 1):

I'll preface this by saying that I'm somewhat biased.  I used to be an [ACE](https://www.acefitness.org/default.aspx?adpos=1t1&creative=116220297204&device=c&matchtype=b&network=g&gclid=CJf9y_z629MCFZCEswod3nQHnA) certified personal trainer.

You make no mention of the time frame, or, the severity of your injury.  If the injury is relatively new, I would suggest you seek the help of a physical therapist first.  Physical therapy can help you regain range of motion and strength in an injured muscle or joint, as well as, provide other modalities to help you rehab more effectively.

Now, if you've already seen a therapist and have been released, hiring a trainer, in the context of rehabbing an injury, would be more beneficial for you.  A certified personal trainer (CPT) will work with your physician or therapist to institute a program to help you to continue to rehab your injury in a safe and efficient manner.  A CPT can insure that you are complying with any medical advice, and, provide feedback on performing exercises.  If you attempt to rehab your injury on your own, you risk re-injuring yourself if you perform an exercise that's contraindicated for your current condition.  If you can afford it, a CPT is the better approach to take.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have noticed in the past couple of months, I have benefited more in terms of muscle mass with having a personally trainer. Of course I do not know your personal preferences but depending on the cost, I would hire a personal trainer.